# How do you call a PowerShell function with an Object of Arguments

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, one can generally call a function with arguments as follows:

```
DoRoutineStuff -Action 'HouseKeeping' -Owner 'Adamma George' -Multiples 4 -SkipEmail
```

To trap these 4 supplied arguments at runtime, one might place this inside the function definition

```
""
"ARGUMENTS:"
$PSBoundParameters
```

And the resulting object displayed might look like so:

```
ARGUMENTS:

Key         Value
---         -----
Action      HouseKeeping
Owner       Adamma George
Multiples   4
SkipEmail   True
```

Now, my question is: If I were to manually build the $MyObject identical to `$PSBoundParameters` displayed above, is there a way to say:

```
RunFunction 'DoRoutineStuff' -oArgument $MyObject
```

Again, if it were to be a script file rather than the function `DoRoutineStuff`, does that make any difference?

**Why might one need to do this?**

Picture a situation where you need to catch the arguments supplied to first script or function, using `$PSBoundParameters`, like so:

```
DoRoutineStuff{

param(
   [string]$Action,
   [string]$Owner,
   [Int]$Multiples,
   [switch]$SkipEmail
)
    $Data = $PSBoundParameters

    #Update one object property
    $Data.Multiples = 1

    #Then, recursively call `DoRoutineStuff` using `$Data`

    #Other tasks
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the language feature you're looking for is [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

You simply pack you're named parameter arguments into a hashtable, store that in a variable and then pass the variable using `@` in front of its name:

```
$myArguments = @{
  Action    = 'HouseKeeping'
  Owner     = 'Adamma George'
  Multiples = 4
  SkipEmail = $true
}
Do-Stuff @myArguments
```

You can also use this technique to only pass a *partial* set of parameter arguments (or none at all), great for passing along *conditional* arguments:

```
$myArguments = @{}

if($someCondition){
    $myArguments['Multiples'] = 1
    $myArguments['SkipEmail'] = $true
}

if($somethingElse){
    $myArguments['Multiple'] = 4
}

Do-Stuff -Action 'HouseKeeping' -Owner 'Adamma George' @myArguments
```

---

You can also reuse `$PSBoundParameters` for splatting further - very useful for proxy functions:

```
function Measure-Files
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$Filter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    return (Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters |Measure-Object -Property Length).Sum
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds very promising. I shall certainly try your recommendations.

Comment: Hey @Mathias, `Splatting` was indeed what I was looking for! I was so sure it had to exist! I had a couple of small hitches implementing the "partial" splatting, but I headed over to `Get-Help about_Splatting` on the console, and behold, there was a really detailed and lucid guide. God bless you Mathias, and God bless SO.